# core data swift sugue not pushing data to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6.1

I have a table view and I want to select an item and have it show all the data for that item in a second view controller. This is my code I am trying to use.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showTea"){
        let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let genView:genViewController = segue.destinationViewController as genViewController
        genView.teaname = selectedIndexPath
```

I get the following error.  'NSIndexPath' is not convertible to 'UILabel'  I am sure I am missing some thing simple but I have not found what it is.

I save the data this way.

```
    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var newItem = dataModel(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newItem.name = Name.text
    newItem.type = Type.text
    newItem.amount = qty.text
    newItem.temp = temp.text
    newItem.time = time.text

    context.save(nil)

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Thanks for all the help. Not sure if this the best way to get it done but it works. genViewContorller below.

```
var myData: Array<AnyObject> = []
@IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var type: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var qty: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var temp: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var time: UILabel!

var row: Int = 0
var tn: String = ""
var ty: String = ""
var qtyl: String = ""
var templ: String = ""
var timel: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    myData = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
    var data: NSManagedObject = myData[row] as NSManagedObject
    var ty = data.valueForKey("type") as String
    var tn = data.valueForKey("name") as String
    var qtyl = data.valueForKey("amount") as String
    var templ = data.valueForKey("temp") as String
    var timel = data.valueForKey("time") as String
    self.name.text = "\(tn)"
    self.type.text = "\(ty)"
    self.qty.text = "\(qtyl)"
    self.temp.text = "\(templ)"
    self.time.text = "\(timel)"
```

I am taking the row value that is being passed via the segue and using it to get the values for each field in that row.

Comment: What do you want the label to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `NSIndexPath` to a `UILabel`.  The compiler error is pretty clear.

Note that you can't update `@IBOutlets` directly because they aren't set up yet (they are still `nil`).  You will need to store your value in a property in the destination view controller, and then update your label in `viewDidLoad`.

1. Add a property in `genViewController` to hold your value.

   ```
   var row: Int = 0
   ```
2. Set the value in `prepareForSegue`.

   ```
   genView.row = selectedIndexPath.row
   ```
3. In `ViewDidLoad` in `genViewController` set up your label:

   ```
   self.teaname.text = "I came from row \(row)"
   ```

Comment: Ok, I was able to follow what you provided and I get the correct row that was selected. Now in the genViewController how do get my text fields 1 - 4 to display the information associated with that row?

Comment: Add properties to your detail view controller for each of the 4 text fields.  In `prepareForSegue` use the selected row to grab the correct info for that row from Core Data and assign the data to the 4 properties in your destination view controller.  Then in `viewDidLoad` set up the text fields using the values of the properties.

Comment: I under stand the detail view controller part.  The in prepareForSegue is where I am hung up.  In genViewController I have var tn: String = "" so in the prepareForSegue genView.tn = ????.

Comment: You haven't give us enough information to help you here.  I don't know where your data is stored or what it is called.  You need to provide more details about how your app is configured.

Comment: I store all my data in CoreData and I do have a dataModel.swift with a class of dataModel. Also in my table view controller I have  var myData: Array<AnyObject> = []

Comment: What do you need to see so that you can finish helping me?

Comment: It would help to know how your data is stored in Core Data.  What Entity names do you have? What attributes do they have and what are their types? What is going into each of your 4 fields in your detail view controller? Do you have an NSManagedObject subclass? If so, what is its structure? How do you put data into Core Data for your project?

Comment: See the save function above and every thing is saved as strings.

Comment: Let me know if my thinking is correct. I have the row number of the data that I want to display in the genView being passed to genView. So should I just be building an NSFetchRequest to build a dicktonary of all the values in associated?

Comment: Apple's sample template for Core Data uses a FetchedResultsController to fill in the tableView data.  Did you start from their template?   How does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` work?  Does it get an object from a FetchedResultsController?  If you have a FetchedResultsController, then you can use the index path to the get the appropriate object, and then read the data from it.