# Swift - segue from custom cell and cell data passing to another controller

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, uitableview

I'm stuck now for hours with a problem when trying to pass data from a tableview custom cell to another viewcontroller.

To be more precise:

- TableViewController1 has CustomCell1 as a Prototype Cell class
- CustomCell1 has Button1, Button2, Label1 and Label2
- ViewController2 has Label3

The TableViewController1 is populated fine and has 10-20 rows of data and everything is displayed fine on screen.

When the user taps on Button1 or Button2 (from what I've seen this triggers the IBAction of the button and not selecting the row) I trigger a segue programmatically from the IBAction of the button I've added to TableViewController1.

What I can't figure out is how to pass the Label1 text when user taps Button1 and Label2 text when user taps Button2 to ViewController2 and display the appropriat text in Label3.

As there is no row selected in the tableview how can this be done if possible?

Thank you!

Kostas

Comment: there is one fast and cheap way - set tag to buttons in respect to row index, for example 1001, 1002 - for button1 and 2001, 2002.. etc for button2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have prepared your segue properly.  That was my hangup when I first tried.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showTea"){
        let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let genView:genViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! genViewController
        genView.row = selectedIndexPath.row

    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "addTea"){

    }
}
```

Then in my genViewController, I added the var row to hold the value for the row so when I pulled the data in genViewController it would pull the correct data.

```
var row: Int = 0
```

See my question on this subject and hope this helps.
[core data swift sugue not pushing data to second view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208659/core-data-swift-sugue-not-pushing-data-to-second-view-controller)